# Motwani-Raghavan 4.10 Ideas

Tags: randomized-algorithms

I'm completely stuck on Problem 4.10 of the Motwani-Raghavan Randomized Algorithms textbook. I don't want an answer, but hints may be helpful here. I understand the general Valiant scheme for the boolean hypercube but am unable to generalize to an arbitrary regular graph:

"Suppose we run Valiant’s scheme on an N-node network in which every node is of degree d; each packet first goes to a random destination chosen uniformly from all the nodes and then on to its final destination. Show that the expected number of steps for the completion of the first phase is 
$
\Omega\left(\frac{\log N}{d \log \log N} + \frac{\log N}{\log d}\right)
$."

I understand that the diameter of any $d$-regular graph is always $O(N/d)$, but am not sure how the analysis would still work in this case as for the hypercube.

I have a feeling that the first term relates to the coupon collector's problem, but am completely unaware of how to get the second term.

Edit: Yuval in the comments essentially has a "workaround" proof that works, but isn't related to the scheme itself, and seems very unintended by the book authors. Is there another solution?

Comment: Have you copied the expression correctly? Since $d \log\log N = \Omega(\log d)$, the expression is actually the same as $\Omega\left(\frac{\log N}{\log d}\right)$.

Comment: The bound $\Omega\left(\frac{\log N}{\log d}\right)$ follows from the fact that there are at most (roughly) $d^t$ nodes at distance at most $t$ from any given node.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes I have copied it correctly.